# Joined line does not match with PlotStyle

Tags: plotting

If I have a list data (http://pastebin.com/RgWLJmTS) which is about to be plotted with

```
ListLogPlot[{data}, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.001]}],
```

But I need to have a plot with a thin line of `Joined` plotted data. With above commend I can not manage the thickness of the `Joined` line!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You incorrectly use the [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html) syntax, please read the second statement under the "Details" section:

> `PlotStyle->{g1,g2,...}` specifies that successive directives `gi`
>   should be used cyclically for successive objects.

For avoiding ambiguity it is recommended to wrap your style directives (which should be applied to *individual dataset*) with `Directive`:

```
ListLogPlot[{data}, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[0.001]]}]
```

> [image: plot]

Another alternative is to add additional curly brackets:

```
ListLogPlot[{data}, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.001]}}]
```

> [image: plot]